# How do the parties choose the location for international treaty?

Tags: international, treaty

How do the parties choose the exact place for carrying out the specific treaty, protocol, or agreement signing act? Can the place of treaty be considered a sign of something? What is the point of signing the treaty outside its participant countries?

Comment: I think the question is a bit broad at the moment: it could be as part of an international conference, or with a third party host or mediator, all sorts of reasons. If it's between two countries, they might not agree who got to host it, particularly if relations between them are hostile. If you have a particular example of one that looks particularly odd , you might want to make the question about that.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding only the 3rd part of the question:

> What is the point of signing the treaty outside its participant countries?

It's rather like a first date between two apartment dwellers.  The parties select some neutral safe location, (*e.g.* a local eatery), and try to find things they like and agree about, if possible; if not possible, the neutral location allows either party to depart at will.